# Optimize SPARQL query for a very large database

Tags: python, query-optimization, sparql, dbpedia, rdflib

Hello I am in need of optimizing my (rather simple) query over a very large database (in particular DBPedia). I'm currently using rdflib and SPARQLWrapper for Python.

Currently I need to do a reachability query, where I provide a source and destination wiki article, a bound *d* and ask if I can reach the destination through at most *d* click through the wikilink within it.

What I am trying is to implement a BFS through this query (example is from Albert Einstein):

```
SELECT ?id
WHERE { 
 ?linkto  a  owl:Thing.
 ?linkto dbo:wikiPageID ?id.
 ?origin    dbo:wikiPageWikiLink  ?linkto.
 ?origin  dbo:wikiPageID 736.
}
```

and then for each neighbor found, I do that query again to find neighbors of neighbors (and so on till the bound is reached). After that I check if the source article is in that list of neighbors to conclude the reachability problem.

Problem as you can imagine is that it takes a very long time to do all of those query. Even with a degree of just 2 (A->B->C, then return all C found), it already takes 20+ seconds to complete. And when I try with a query to just return the number of all neighbors of degree 4, that took 30 second to complete (UPDATE: when I try again today, it just return an error, timeout I guess, last I tried it returned 1+ Million article)

```
SELECT ?article (count(distinct ?neighbor4) as ?ncount)
WHERE {
     ?neighbor1 a owl:Thing.
     ?neighbor2 a owl:Thing.
     ?neighbor3 a owl:Thing.
     ?neighbor4 a owl:Thing.
     ?article dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?neighbor1.
     ?neighbor1 dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?neighbor2.
     ?neighbor2 dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?neighbor3.
     ?neighbor3 dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?neighbor4.
     ?article dbo:wikiPageID 736.
}
```

So I would like to ask if there's anything I can do to optimize/improve the performance of it. I've been looking around and seeing the following option:

1. Setup a local SPARQL endpoint
2. Download the rdf file contains the triple I need and work with that file: Since I only need the wikilink relation, I already find the file contains just that from DBPedia. But the compressed file is already almost 2GB, I'd guess uncompressed that would be 30+ or so GB, can rdflib parse such a large file?

Do you have any idea what I can do for my situation? (maybe another library, other smarter ways to query,...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I've answered to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875226/sparql-query-to-return-number-of-neighbor/70445602#70445602), RDFLib is not suitable for very large amounts of data such as DBpedia and complex queries. For those use cases, better use a dedicated triple store such as Virtuoso Opensource 7, which you can easily setup using Docker.

As for other libraries, the paper [Graph-XLL: a Graph Library for Extra Large Graph Analytics on a Single Machine](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8900744) could be a good resource. They present their own approach and also note other approaches like the igraph R library and NetworkX for Python. I would start with NetworkX first as you are already using Python, and if that cannot process the data investigate the other libraries.